# How to show different view controller based on RowSelected in Tableviewcell?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am new to iPhone Development and trying to create a small application(Recipe list) with multiple views. When the user selects one of the rows in tablecell, I would like to call a new view. For Instance, the menu card with items mushroom, pasta,steak must call another view with detailed recipe.

I have used UITableViewController to display a list of items with Accessory. These items are dynamically populated from a NSArray. When the user taps on one of the rows in the table, it should take him to a view controller based on the Row Selection. I know I have to implement tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: function to call the appropriate view.
But I am not able to proceed. I read about Segue in storyboards, but even that seems a bit confusing for me.

I would really appreciate if someone solves my query. Here is my code.

RecipeViewController.h

```
    #import "RecipeViewController.h"
    #import "Recipe.h"

    @interface RecipeViewController ()

    @end

@implementation RecipeViewController

{
    NSArray *recipes; //Recipe Array
}

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.navigationItem.title = @"Hotel";
    UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:nil action:nil];
    [[self navigationItem] setBackBarButtonItem:backButton];

    // Create recipe array for main screen. 

    Recipe *recipe1 = [Recipe new];
    recipe1.headline = @"Mushroom";
    recipe1.description = @"description";
    recipe1.imageFile = @"mushroom.jpg";

    Recipe *recipe2 = [Recipe new];
    recipe2.headline = @"pasta";
    recipe2.description = @"Pasta description";
    recipe2.imageFile = @"pasta.jpg";

    Recipe *recipe3 = [Recipe new];
    recipe3.headline = @"Steak";
    recipe3.description = @"Steak description";
    recipe3.imageFile = @"steak.jpg";


    recipes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:recipe1, recipe2, recipe3,nil];

    // Remove table cell separator
    [self.tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];

    // Assign custom backgroud for the view
    self.parentViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"welcome_screen"]];
    self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    // Add padding to the top of the table view
    UIEdgeInsets inset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 0, 0, 0);
    self.tableView.contentInset = inset;

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return recipes.count;
}

- (UIImage *)cellBackgroundForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSInteger rowCount = [self tableView:[self tableView] numberOfRowsInSection:0];
    NSInteger rowIndex = indexPath.row;
    UIImage *background = nil;

    if (rowIndex == 0) {
        background = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cell_top.png"];
    } else if (rowIndex == rowCount - 1) {
        background = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cell_bottom.png"];
    } else {
        background = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cell_middle.png"];
    }

    return background;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    // Configure the cell...
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Display recipe in the table cell
    Recipe *recipe = [recipes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    UIImageView *recipeImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
    recipeImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:recipe.imageFile];

    UILabel *recipeNameLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:101];
    recipeNameLabel.text = recipe.headline;

    UILabel *recipeDetailLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:102];
    recipeDetailLabel.text = recipe.description;

    // Assign our own background image for the cell
    UIImage *background = [self cellBackgroundForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    UIImageView *cellBackgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:background];
    cellBackgroundView.image = background;
    cell.backgroundView = cellBackgroundView;


    return cell;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


    CampusViewController *campusViewController;
WhoViewController *whoViewController;



    switch (indexPath.row) 
 {
         case 0:
          campusViewController=[[CampusViewController alloc] init];  
             [[self navigationController] pushViewController:campusViewController      animated:YES];

        break;

    case 1:
        whoViewController=[[WhoViewController alloc] init];   // not released as ARC is   included in the project
        [[self navigationController] pushViewController:whoViewController animated:YES];
        break;
    case 2:

        break;
    case 3:

        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

}

```
 - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
 {
 if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ShowDetails"]) {
  RecipeViewController *detailViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
  NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:sender];

    /* NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
 detailViewController.data = [self.dataController objectInListAtIndex:indexPath.row]; 

    */

      }



   }

    @end
```

---

//  Recipe.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Recipe : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *headline; // name of recipe
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *description; // recipe detail
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *imageFile; // image filename of recipe

@end
```

Comment: @LuisCien I have edited my didSelectRowatIndexPath method in the code snippet above.

Answer (score 0):

Have you read any tutorials on how to do this? This is a very basic question and there are a lot of posts about this out there.
I'll only give you an explanation on how to do it but you will have to code it yourself.

The standard way we go about an application that shows the user different view controllers based on the selection of a `UITableViewCell` is by using a `UINavigatorController`. This controller gives you the methods:

- – pushViewController:animated:
- – popViewControllerAnimated:

... among others. With these two methods you can go back and forth between view controllers, which is what you want to do. So you have to give your navigator controller the table view controller that you already have. You can do that by using `UINavigatorController`'s method `– initWithRootViewController:`

A little example of what your `– tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath:` might look like is:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UIViewController *myViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"YourNibName" bundle:nil];
    self.navigationController pushViewController:[myViewController autorelease] animated:YES];
}
```

Hope this helps!

Further reading:

- [UINavigationController tutorial Ray Wenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1)
- [UINavigationController tutorial Techotopia](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Creating_a_Navigation_based_iOS_5_iPhone_Application_using_TableViews)

Comment: I read your tutorials. But I am not able to proceed further. In your example, you have specified a Nib Name. Whereas, I am using Storyboards.